# Wouldn't a program with only the line of fork() break itself?

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

   fork();

   return 0;

}
```

In my understanding, fork() will copy the parent's process, and run it as a child process; if that was the case, would the program above break? Because how I am understanding this program is: the program above will call fork() indefinitely, and eventually cause a Stack Overflow.

Comment: In addition to what everyone pointed out,  I believe technically the child should use _exit(); instead of the parent call to exit(). (You used return in your example which both would call exit() )

Comment: @lundman It's OK in this case because the parent doesn't do any I/O or register any `atexit` handlers before calling `fork`, and because the program isn't using `vfork`.

Comment: Yeah, but lets get them on good habits from the start :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fork` call does not make either the child or the parent process go back to the beginning of `main` and start over.  It returns like a normal function, but it does it twice, once in the child and once in the parent, with different return values so you can tell which is which.

So, in your program, `fork` succeeds and then both processes go on to the `return 0` and exit.  Nothing bad will happen.

A variation *will* cause problems, though:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    for (;;)
        fork();
    /* not reached */
}
```

This is called a "fork bomb".  Because it calls `fork` inside an infinite loop, never checking whether it's the parent or the child, the original process becomes two processes, and then four, and then eight, and ... until you run out of RAM, or at least process IDs.  And it doesn't check for failure either, so it doesn't stop after the `fork` calls start failing.  All of these processes will continue chewing up CPU forever, and none of the other programs running on the computer will be able to make forward progress.

Back in the days of mammoths and SunOS 4 it was even worse than that, a fork bomb would be liable to tickle a kernel bug and outright crash the minicomputer, and then the [BOFH](http://users.bestweb.net/~bofh/) would come looking for you and he or she would not be happy.  I would expect a modern kernel not to *crash*, and you might even be able to kill off the entire exponential process tree with control-C, but I'm not going to try it just to find out.

Incidentally, `return_type whatever()` is bad style in C, because for historical reasons it means `whatever` takes *any number of arguments*.  Always write `return_type whatever(void)` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Not only you gave an answer to my question, but you also explained why the given answer is correct. At the same time, you also gave me a deeper insight on the subject. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html):

> Both processes shall continue to execute from the *fork()* function.

So, both processes will continue after the call to `fork()`, and both will immediately terminate.